# Is there a way to get the body of a Laravel Mail object to store in a variable?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail

I'm using the Laravel Mail API to generate mailables and send them out.
Everything is working fine with that.

However, I also want to log the email bodies in the DB.
In order to do that though, I need to first get the bodies of the emails I'm sending out.

In the Laravel docs, they have a snippet about how to output an email to the browser here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#previewing-mailables-in-the-browser

However, I don't want to output the email to the browser. I want to store it in a variable.
Is that possible? If so, how? Thanks.

Like the docs suggested, I tried something like the following:

```
$body = new App\Mail\InvoicePaid($invoice);
```

However, I got an error saying that I have to actually return the new Mail object in order for it to work (i.e., do what they do in the example code in the docs).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Previous paragraph](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#rendering-mailables) tells you how to capture the rendered template:

```
$html = (new App\Mail\InvoicePaid($invoice))->render();
echo $html;
```

Comment: Completely missed that! Thanks a million. (Feels like an idiot now.)